# How can I contact Stack Overflow marketing about sponsoring a conference?

Tags: support

I am the finance lead for the 2020 useR! conference for users of the open source statistical software R.  I would like to contact someone at Stack Overflow to discuss possible sponsorship opportunities.  Any suggestions as to how I might do that?

Comment: Not 100% sure where we route these now - asking around.

Comment: My best guess would be the advertising section of the Contact Us page. Seems like it would fall under that umbrella. Or at least, seems like a good place to start asking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

thanks for reaching out!

You can send these proposals along via /contact - we'll add 'em to Marketing's queue. No promises on whether we can actually do anything (we're a small company with limited time and a limited budget) but we'll at least look it over & see if it's something that fits into what we're planning.